# tar "no such file or directory" error during Scala installation

Tags: command-line, bashrc, tar, scala

I followed these steps to download and install scala but faced some issues.

#### Install Scala

1. First download scala-2.12.1.tgz from the scala site
2. Then run the following commands in the terminal

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/local/src/scala
   sudo tar -xvf sscala-2.12.1 .tgz -C /usr/local/src/scala/nano .bashrc
   ```

   after that add this variable at the end of opened `.bashrc` file

   ```
   export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.12.1
   export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   . .bashrc
   ```

When I wrote the 2nd command in terminal it showed

```
tar: usr/local/src/scala/nano.bashrc: cannot open: no such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: existing now.
```

I need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: The command says `/usr/local/src/scala/nano .bashrc` with a space in between, the error says `usr/local/src/scala/nano.bashrc` without a space. Please double check the commands you ran and the manual you're using.

Comment: i've run the command without space but it still shows the same error.

Comment: @KashfUlHUdha FYI [`scala is packaged on all supported Ubuntu versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=scala). On 14.04 LTS you will get 2.9, on newer versions - you get 2.11. It is unclear why you self-extracted non-supported later installation....

Comment: BTW, adding `. .bashrc` to `.bashrc` is a bad idea. You won't be able to use Bash on your account if you do that, until you remove it that line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the following error:

```
tar: usr/local/src/scala/nano.bashrc: cannot open: no such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: existing now.
```

because you didn't extract the contents of scala-2.12.1.tgz because of a typo error. Instead of:

```
sudo tar -xvf sscala-2.12.1 .tgz -C /usr/local/src/scala/nano .bashrc
```

The correct commands should be:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/src/scala/  
sudo tar -xvf scala-2.12.1.tgz -C /usr/local/src/scala/  
nano .bashrc
```

These commands will solve the immediate problem in the question, however it should be noted that according to the official [Scala website](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.12.1.html) the most popular way to get Scala is either using Scala through sbt, the Scala build tool, or to use Scala through an IDE. Using Scala through IntelliJ IDE is recommended for beginners who are not familiar with the command line. The free *intellij-idea-community* snap package can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following commands:

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
```

In Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 the package name of the required Java 8 JDK in the default Ubuntu repositories is *openjdk-8-jdk* and it can be installed by the following command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Run the following commands to export the path to SCALA_HOME to the PATH variable.

```
export SCALA_HOME="/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.12.1"
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank u this issue is solved. now .bashrc file is opened.

Comment: I've already installed jdk.

Comment: Can u plz tell me how to add those variables in .bashrc file???