# What is the equivalent command to pathmunge in CentOS?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I have some installation [instructions](https://blacksaildivision.com/how-to-install-openssl-on-centos) but they use `pathmunge` which caused me an error in Ubuntu. What is the equivalent syntax to the following script to do the same in Ubuntu?

```
/etc/profile.d/openssl.sh
pathmunge /usr/local/openssl/bin
```

I did add pathmunge command to Ubuntu using this answer:

run nano `~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc` and paste this:

```
pathmunge () {
        if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
           if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
              PATH=$PATH:$1
           else
              PATH=$1:$PATH
           fi
        fi
}
```

When I login, I get this error:

[image: error loading /etc/profile.d/openssh.sh]

Comment: @karel I did not get that answer you posted. Can you please provide me clear syntax on how to do the line I posted in Ubunut? I am not a Linux user so not familiar with that.

Comment: For example, the commands at the end of this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060474/tar-no-such-file-or-directory-error-during-scala-installation/1060476#1060476 prepend a path, which is stored in a variable named  $SCALA_HOME, to the PATH variable.

Comment: So is just replacing `pathmunge` with `export` is all what it needs?

Comment: @user9371654 Essentially yes. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/openssl/bin`

Comment: You never normally need to `export` PATH though, because it is already in the environment (you can think of it as being already exported) (cc @SergiyKolodyazhnyy). It's enough to write `PATH=$PATH:/thing/I/want/to/append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently in RHEL and CentOS, `pathmunge` is a shell function declared in `/etc/profile` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013051/3701431)). You can simply  add  that very same function to your `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` (which needs to be sourced after you add the function).

For simplicity, run `nano ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc` and paste this:

```
pathmunge () {
        if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
           if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
              PATH=$PATH:$1
           else
              PATH=$1:$PATH
           fi
        fi
}
```

Save the file after pasting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (that's lowercase o, not zero), and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. The command will be available for use after that.

Alternatively, you can just add directory to `PATH` by hand, temporarily as in `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/openssl/bin` , or permanently as provided in [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) by modifying `/etc/profile` (global for all users) or better by modifying `~/.bashrc` file if you just need this for your user.

Comment: If I will paste this code you posted for pathmunge, what should I name the file? using what extension?

Comment: @user9371654 Please reread the answer. This is supposed to go into your `~/.bashrc` file. Once you paste it there, run ` source .bashrc`. The function will be available for use after that. No need for files or extensions

Comment: Your answer said just run `sudo nano` this opens new file. You did not clarify I should edit an exisiting file.

Comment: @user9371654 Ok, I thought that was clear. I can edit that

Comment: I added the code for pathmunge to ~/.bashrc. I added the script that uses pathmunge. When I start my machine I get error message saying: error found when loading /etc/profile. ~/.bashrc and that it can not find pathmunge.

Comment: can you plz look at my OP edit? I posted the error message.

Comment: @user9371654  OK, after reading the tutorial you linked,  the command is apparently required globally not just in `~/.bashrc`, although it's entirely unnecessary. Let's just put `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/openssl/bin` into `/etc/profile.d/openssl.sh` and see if that works.

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks. If you can update this to the answer please? it will be more complete and will accept it.